# Mostrar "activity" con un Edittext multiline

Tags: android, edittext

La verdad no se como explicar bien lo que necesito por ende, usare una imagen para hacerme entender lo que busco es lo siguiente.
Al presionar un botón muestra lo siguiente apareciendo de la parte inferior hacia arriba.
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que tengo es lo siguiente en el **XML** pero lo muestra como **Dialog**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/content_enviar_tipo_dialogo"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
tools:context="com.example.hp14.iteracion2.Asistente.EnviarTipoDialogo"
tools:showIn="@layout/activity_enviar_tipo_dialogo">
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

    <TextView
        android:text="Envía tu inquietud, realizando una pregunta acorde del tema. "
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
        android:id="@+id/textView" />

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        android:ems="10"
        android:id="@+id/txtenviar"
        android:maxLines="2"
        android:hint="Escribir..."
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Enviar"
        android:id="@+id/btnenviar"
        android:background="@drawable/boton2"
        android:layout_below="@+id/txtenviar"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

¿ alguna idea para realizar esta tarea ?

Answer (score 1):

Si deseas tener un EditText multilineas, debes hacer uso de la propiedad:

```
android:inputType="textMultiLine"
```

puedes definir el número de lineas a desplegar por default:

```
android:lines="5"
```

así como un minimo y máximo:

```
 android:minLines="2" 
 android:maxLines="10"
```

es recomendable habilitar las barras de scroll vertical:

```
  android:scrollbars="vertical"
```

Este es un ejemplo:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/myedittext"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine" 
    android:lines="5" 
    android:minLines="2"
    android:maxLines="10"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"/>
```

Comment: Y cómo podría que este "Layout" aparesca de abajo hacia arriba, el problema es que este edittext está en un estilo dialog y el teclado tapa el botón que por debajo del edittext

Comment: ahhh ahora entiendo, bueno el sistema operativo automáticamente mueve el Edittext hacia arriba para evitar se tape, por lo que ahora entiendo es que quieres que se vea el botón "publicar" de la imagen?

Comment: disculpa la demora, si asi es, necesito es mismo diseño, pero si notas el aparece de abajo hacia arriba ...